# Trying to solve the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}(x-(a+i b))} dx$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha<1$

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

I am trying to solve the integral
$$I_{\alpha}:=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}(x-(a+i b))} dx,$$ $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha <1$.

Mathematica gives

$$I_{\alpha}=e^{-z} \left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{\alpha} \Gamma (1-\alpha) \Gamma (\alpha,-z)$$
provided that $\Im(z)\neq 0\lor \Re(z)<0$. Here $z=a+ i b$.

Assuming that $a,b>0$, and trying to use the residue theory on the contour
( ($\arg{z}=0,\, 0<|z|<R$), ($0 \leq \arg{z}\leq \pi/2,\, |z|=R$), ($\arg{z}=\pi/2,\, 0<|z|<R$) ),  one gets  an integral on the segment that lies on the imaginary axis that is  equally difficult to (but different from) the integral one gets on the contour segment that lies on the real axis. This is easy to see just by looking at the factor $x-(a+i b)$ in the denominator of the integrand.

If we use real-variable methods, we must solve
$$J_{\alpha}:=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}(x-a)}{x^{\alpha}(
(x-a)^2+b^2)} dx,$$
and

$$H_{\alpha}:=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}b}{x^{\alpha}(
(x-a)^2+b^2)} dx.$$

Then $I_{\alpha}=J_{\alpha}+i H_{\alpha}$.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You may tell us that $z:=a+ib$. The result comes from [$(8.6.4)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.6.E4) in the DLMF. It is not hard to derive it from the definition of the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Gary. The link is super useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\Re z<0$ and $\alpha<1$. Then
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ - x} x^{ - \alpha } }}{{x - z}}dx} & = \int_0^\infty  {e^{ - x} x^{ - \alpha } \left( {\int_0^\infty  {e^{ - (x - z)t} dt} } \right)dx} \\ & = \int_0^{ \infty } {e^{zt} \left( {\int_0^\infty  {e^{ - (1 + t)x} x^{ - \alpha } dx} } \right)dt} 
\\ & = \int_0^\infty  {e^{zt} (1 + t)^{\alpha  - 1} \left( {\int_0^\infty  {e^{ - s} s^{ - \alpha } ds} } \right)dt} \\ & = \Gamma (1 - \alpha )\int_0^\infty  {e^{zt} (1 + t)^{\alpha  - 1} dt} 
\\ & = e^{ - z} \Gamma (1 - \alpha )\int_1^\infty  {e^{zu} u^{\alpha  - 1} du} \\ & = e^{ - z} \Gamma (1 - \alpha )( - z)^{ - \alpha } \int_{ - z}^\infty  {e^{ - v} v^{\alpha  - 1} dv} \\ & = e^{ - z} \Gamma (1 - \alpha )( - z)^{ - \alpha } \Gamma (\alpha , - z).
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't know how to justify the complex change of variables $zu \to -v$ that gives $\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{zu}u^{\alpha-1} du=(-z)^{-\alpha}\int_{-z}^{\infty}e^{-v} v^{\alpha-1}dv$. Also, the upper limit $\infty$, should not it be $z\infty$ ?

Comment: It is $-z\infty$ which is still $\infty$. You can rotate it to the positive axis using Cauchy's theorem if you like. Alternatively, you can assume $z<0$ initially and appeal to analytic continuation in the end.

Comment: "You can rotate it to the positive axis using Cauchy's theorem if you like" you mean justify it using a contour integral ? If so, I have a problem: $e^{zu}u^{\alpha-1}$ is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: The contour starts at $-z$, which is, by assumption, in the right-half plane.

Comment: Would you like to give this question a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494002/can-taylor-series-expansion-be-used-to-represent-integrands-outside-interval-of/4494122?noredirect=1#comment9428582_4494122

Answer (score 4):

We can evaluate the integral using Feynman's trick

We start by introducing a new function.
$$I(a,t,z)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^ae^{-t(x+z)}}{x+z}dx$$
provided that $t≥0$.

We easily find $I(a,\infty,z)=0$

When we take the derivative with respect to $t$, our integral simplifies using the gamma function after subbing $u=tx$
$$\partial_t\space I(a,t,z)=-\int_0^\infty x^ae^{-t(x+z)}dx=-t^{-a-1}e^{-zt}\Gamma(a+1).$$
Using $I(a,\infty,z)=0$, we get
$$J(a,z)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^ae^{-x}}{x+z}dx=e^z\left(I(a,1,z)-I(a,\infty,z)\right)=e^z\int_\infty^1\partial_t\space I(a,t,z)dt$$
$$=e^z\int_\infty^1\left(-t^{-a-1}e^{-zt}\Gamma(a+1)\right)=e^z\Gamma(a+1)\int_1^\infty t^{-a-1}e^{-zt}dt.$$
Substitute $u=zt$
$$J(a,z)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^ae^{-x}}{x+z}dx=z^ae^z\Gamma(a+1)\int_z^\infty u^{-a-1}e^{-u}du=z^ae^z\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(-a,z)$$
Finally:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x^a(x-z)}dx=J(-a,-z)=(-z)^ae^{-z}\Gamma(1-a)\Gamma(a,-z)$$