# Can Taylor series expansion be used to represent integrands outside interval of pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, asymptotics

**Edited to be more precise:**.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth bounded function. Assume that the Taylor series expansion of $f$ around $x=0$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(0)+R_{n}(x),\qquad\qquad (1)$$
has radius of convergence $1$. Suppose also that $\psi\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, consider the problem of finding an asymptotic expansion for the integral
$$I(\epsilon):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi(x)f(\epsilon x) dx.$$

Question:
Assuming that the integral
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi(x) R_{n}(x)dx$ exists for $k=1,\dots,n$, and is finite, can one substitute for $f$ with its expansion $(1)$ into $I(\epsilon)$?

Precisely, assuming that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^k\psi(x)  dx$ exists, is it correct to write

$$I(\epsilon)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(0) \epsilon^k}{k!}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^k\psi(x)  dx+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi(x)R_{n}(\epsilon x)  dx$$

My concern is about the last term $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi(x)R_{n}(\epsilon x)  dx$. Because even though $f$ is bounded, there is no guarantee that the remainder $R_{n}$ is bounded outside the interval $(-1,1)$ where the expansion (1) no longer represents $f$.

If the support of $\psi$ is contained in $(-1/\epsilon,1/\epsilon)$ then $R_{n}(\epsilon x)\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But what if $\psi$ does not have a compact support.

Comment: do you want the expansion for $\epsilon\to 0$?

Comment: Yes. The asymptotic as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. But this is a good point. It raises the question about the asymptotic behaviour of $I(\lambda)$ as $\lambda\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: If you expand around $x_0$, then its powers $(x-x_0)^k$, not $x^k$.

Comment: @ emacs drives me nuts Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For small $\epsilon$ the point is that by the time $f(\epsilon x)$ deviates by very much from $f(0)$, $\psi(x)$ is already small, while $f$ is bounded, so the whole integrand is small out there. This means what you wrote can indeed be used as an asymptotic expansion provided the integrals with the monomials converge. If they don't all converge then you can try to introduce a tuning parameter to cut off the domain of integration (which generally won't hurt anything especially if $f$ is bounded).

In the opposite regime there is no reason to believe this will do anything useful unless $f$ is analytic.

Comment: Thanks @Ian. Your answer matches my intuition. Can we make this more rigorous ? What kind of conditions should be satisfied by $\int (x-x_{0})^{k}  \psi$ ?

Comment: @Medo Well first of all for it to work the way you wrote it you need $x_0=0$. To move that you need $f(\epsilon x + x_0)$ instead. Besides that as I said you will need the integrals against monomials to converge to make this work without any cutoff. But making it rigorous is easier when using a cutoff anyway.